# Region of Interest using opencv

Tags: opencv

I have use cvSetImageRoi(img,cvRect(...));
but the ROI crop out is not as clear as we human can see on the original image. It's look like the ROI has been zoomed in. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nash Ruddin has some excellent articles on OpenCV that I've found very helpful. There's one on ROI as well that contains a decent blurb on the topic: [OpenCV Region of Interest (ROI)](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29)

Essentially, you're right about what's going on. You've 'zoomed' in on the image to localise your processing to a specific area. It's not that setting an ROI has affected the image, it's only set a focus to a lower-resolution part of the image. After your processing on the area is finished, you can reset the ROI:

```
  cvResetImageROI(img);
```

... and that will be a bit clearer to see again.

Comment: thank you for the explanation.it make myself more clearer now.